# Karp hardness of two cycles which lengths differ by one

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, np

Our problem is as follows:

> **NEARLY**-**EQUAL**-**CYCLE**-**PAIR**
>
> **Input**: An undirected graph $G(V,E)$
>
> **Output**: **YES** if there exists $2$ (simple) cycles in $G$ which lengths differ by $1$, otherwise **NO**

Is it $NP$-complete?

Comment: There is also: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Bondy and Vince (J. Graph Theory, 1998) proved that any graph of minimum degree three contains cycles of lengths differing by 1 or 2. This was generalised and strengthened by Fan (J. Combin. Theory Ser. B, 2002) to get many cycles of lengths differing by 2 or 1. This does not solve your problem, but it does tell you that the "gadgets" used in a hardness reduction might need to be quite sparse.

Comment: To restrain the *supposed* gadget, Theorem 2 of Bondy and Vince's [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/50fb/6ffa5be56ad459a672dec8f92764a3973017.pdf) would do it better than Theorem 1 which is referred in your comment.Since, in Theorem 2, we are sure that the two cycle lengths differ by exactly $1$. Even under the restriction of Theorem 2, the supposed gadget only needs to be **sparse somewhere**. It may still contain some **dense** parts.

Comment: As is answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/99616/90560), the construction still contains some **posisibly dense** part (the original bipartite graph), but necessarily contains a quite sparse part (the odd-length cycle).